# Closing array fetching php

Tags: php, sql

I have a following SQL table:

```
+----------------+----------------+------------------+
| country        | region         | city             | 
+----------------+----------------+------------------+
| South Africa   | KwaZulu-Natal  | Durban           | 
| South Africa   | Gauteng        | Johannesburg     |
| South Africa   | Gauteng        | Tshwane          |
| South Africa   | KwaZulu-Natal  | Pietermaritzburg | 
| United Kingdom | Greater London | City of London   |
| United Kingdom | Greater London | Wimbledon        |
+----------------+----------------+------------------+
```

My code in PHP:

```
$result = $link -> query( "select * from city" );

$row = $result -> fetch_array();
echo $row['city'];
// Output: Durban

$row1 = $result -> fetch_array();
echo $row1['city'];
// Output: Johannesburg
```

When I try to fetch arrays from one result it excludes those arrays from other variables. That means if I fetched 1 table row into an array and put it into variable $row I can't use it anywhere it else in the code with other variable. It is hard to explain but I need it for loop purposes. 
So my question is if it's somehow possible to reset result fetching. So that both outputs in example shown above would be 'Durban' 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you want always  the same result  ???

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use the results of your query more than once in the same script then unload all the results into a local array first and then use that array as many times as you like.

```
$result = $link -> query( "select * from city" );
$cities = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Now `$cities` contains all the results and you can reuse it more than once.

```
echo $cities[0]['city'];  // = Durban
```

Or in a loop

```
foreach ($cities as $city){
    echo $city['city'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [mysqli_result::data_seek](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php):

```
$result->data_seek(0);
```